# How to continuous UI development in java?

Tags: java, tomcat

So I come from ruby on rails background.
I am working on this java project.I am fairly new to java.

I maybe wrong but It seems unlike other technologies ,one compiles the project in a war file then deploy's that on tomcat.

The original assets are in src directory that are be checked in the source directory.
Where as to make any changes in assets files that being css/javascripts/images one need to 
make changes in the target directory of the tomcat to preview them on the browser.

This makes development tricky and complex as I can't use branches, since branches work on src directory of my local repository but the changes I make are in the target directory. Also I would like to use sass and haml like features in java.  What frameworks or other web servers or any other strategy are my options .

I have heard of groovy on grails but for some reason we want to stick to java the language

Comment: Most IDEs will auto-deploy artifacts like JS, CSS, JSP, etc.

Comment: I don't want to use IDE's they are to slow and I prefer sublime text to do my ui development.

Comment: You can deploy an exploded .war project on tomcat and achieve the result you are looking for. You do not need to use the tomcat manager to deploy apps

Comment: Maybe I am wrong but won't the tomcat look for assets in target directory instead of source.

Comment: You are indeed very wrong if you think tomcat looks at a source or target directory. Tomcat looks at the deployed directory, as in what is in 'webapps'. HOWEVER, it is possible through a configuration file to tell tomcat to look somewhere else; I suspect that the latter is true for your development environment.

Comment: take a quick look at <http://bayou.io>, it might interest you.

Comment: @zevy_boy If your project is set up in an IDE you don't need to use it to *edit* if it automatically deploys on changes. Otherwise set up a process that copies changed files, change your webapp's root, etc.

Comment: @DaveNewton since I am working on the UI aspects sublime text is the preferred editor. So I am against using IDE. I think I can look into the alternative solution of changing the webapp root.

Edit: prefered ,best was too strong.

Comment: @zevy_boy That's an opinion, of course; IDEs offer better JavaScript support, and a wider range of intelligent DOM-based operations as opposed to ST2/3's regex-based functionality. While I'm a regular ST2/3 user, "best" is highly subjective, and varies based on what you're actually doing. There's stuff you can do in an IDE you just can't do in ST2/3 even with plugins. And again, I'm not suggesting using the IDE as your editor, I'm suggesting using it because they have significantly better support for Java EE projects across the board.

Answer (score 0):

Look into using a build tool like maven or gradle to build your project. They both have a jetty plugin with a jettyRun goal that will run your project out of your source directory using embedded jetty. So if you are making changes to the assets, you just have to refresh the browser.

Another alternative is to configure tomcat to serve your assets up as static files from your workspace while you're doing development.

Or as @DaveNewton suggested, you can use your IDE to auto deploy